# How can I delete a user account in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am creating an application by combining Django Rest Framework and Angular.
Please let us know about the implementation of user deletion, because there are places that will not work.

I described in Djnago's views.py about the deletion view as follows.

```
class AuthInfoDeleteView(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    lookup_field = 'email'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        try:
            instance = self.queryset.get(email=self.request.user)
            return instance
        except Account.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

email is stored in `self.request.user`.
In addition, I write in serializer.py as follows.

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Account, AccountManager


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'profile', 'password', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Account.objects.create_user(request_data=validated_data)
```

In this state, when sending a method of Angular to DELETE to the URL(/api/user/delete/) to which AuthInfoDeleteView is linked, the following error occurred.

```
Internal Server Error: /api/user/delete/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/auth_django_and_angular2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/auth_django_and_angular2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/auth_django_and_angular2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/auth_django_and_angular2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/auth_django_and_angular2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/auth_django_and_angular2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/auth_django_and_angular2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/auth_django_and_angular2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/auth_django_and_angular2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 219, in delete
    return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/auth_django_and_angular2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 93, in destroy
    self.perform_destroy(instance)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/auth_django_and_angular2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 97, in perform_destroy
    instance.delete()
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
[24/Jun/2017 14:04:42] "DELETE /api/user/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 500 15690
```

How can I properly delete accounts correctly?
I need your help.

Comment: Can you post full traceback?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner  I added.

Answer (score 2):

Try editing your view like this,

```
try: 
    instance = self.queryset.get(email=self.request.user.email) 
    return instance 
except Account.DoesNotExist: 
    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not disabling the account instead of deleting it?

That was my approach. In my view class (which I use for the extended UserProfile and inherits from RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView) I overwrite the destroy method like this:

```
def destroy(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):

    request.user.is_active = False
    request.user.save()

    return Response(status=204)
```

I use Token authentication (using rest_auth) and after disabling the account, tokens are no longer valid (the response when trying to use them is "User inactive or deleted".

I think its best practice to disable accounts instead of deleting them.

Comment: Why its best practice @jeudyx? If in frontend we are providing button for deleting my account but actually we are deactivating it instead of deleting it, then is it not a breach of privacy? It would be like saying one thing and then doing another.

Comment: It depends on your system and your terms of use. Many systems only disable the account and if the user requests a total removal of their data, then their request is processed. Depending on how you design your database, if you remove the user account, every record on all other tables will also be deleted.

Its not a breach of privacy because nobody external to the system is accesing the data, but I do understand your concern.

Comment: Not deleting data when the user has requested it is a breach of GDPR.